# Why such different behavior with the same script?

Tags: bash, shell-script, ssh, pipe

Check this out:

```bsh
$ cat /tmp/test-ssh.sh
#!/bin/bash

ssh -T git@bitbucket.org || exit 1
echo continue

$ bash -x /tmp/test-ssh.sh
+ ssh -T git@bitbucket.org
authenticated via ssh key.

You can use git to connect to Bitbucket. Shell access is disabled
+ echo continue
continue
```

Yes, all looks good. Now, the same file invoking another way:

```bsh
~$ cat /tmp/test-ssh.sh | bash -x
+ ssh -T git@bitbucket.org
authenticated via ssh key.

You can use git to connect to Bitbucket. Shell access is disabled

$ echo $?
0

$ lsb_release -a 
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Debian
Description:    Debian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye)
Release:        11
Codename:       bullseye
```

Why such different behavior with the same script?

Comment: SSH probably eats the rest of stdin

Comment: Ahh... thx a lot for such quick reply!!